# remove the append from filled in fields

Tags: jquery, field

this is the code that I wrote:

```
$('#third_step input[type=text]').each(function(n,element){  
            if ($(element).val()=='') {  
              //alert('Field '+element.id+' must have a value');  
              $("label[for='" +element.id+ "']").append('<p class="input_field_error">Bitte füllen Sie dieses Feld!</p>');
        error++;  
            }else{
        $('.input_field_error').remove();
        }
 });
```

Then when I test it, I click submit and the fields that are not filled in they show the error message, but when I fill in some of them then the error mesagge is removed from them plus it removes the message from the fields that are before them, and the fields after them still have the error message! maybe I need to select the input_field_error from those labels that have their fields filled! Or this is not a good way to test the fields if they are filled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.input_field_error').remove();
```

This will remove ALL elements with a class of `input_field_error` which is not what you want. You want to remove ONLY the element that is the one you are currently validating. So change it to:

```
$('.input_field_error', 'label[for="' + element.id + '"]').remove();
```

This will only select the `input_field_error` class WITHIN the `<label>` with the current ID.

Comment: I think you mean `$('label[for="'+element.id+'"] .input_field_error')` Your version is selecting all the input errors and label with that id.

Comment: @idrumgood thank you this did the trick, I knew I had to do this but I am new to jquery and I didnt know how to select only the label for the field which is filled! but there is another problem, everytime I click the submit button the append function repeats its self, so it duplicates the error! is there any other option to replace the append function?

Comment: @Syon Nope. Notice the comma separating the two selectors, then see here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1. The second selector gives the context in which to find the first.

Comment: @idrumgood Ahh - well I learned something new :) I've never used the context before. I'll have to remember that. +1'

Answer (score 0):

You need to adjust your else statement so that it does not remove all class elements. $('.input_field_error') references ALL items.